# Squareup Account is not enabled for card processing exception

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm having a squareup developer account which I use to integrate squareup with our project. When I try to process a charge using their payment form (I used the sample project hosted in their [github](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/java_payment)) i'm getting this exception.

```
com.squareup.connect.ApiException: {"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"CARD_PROCESSING_NOT_ENABLED","detail":"Account is not enabled for card processing, visit www.squareup.com/activate"}]}
```

I'm using squareup [test cards](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/testing/test-values)

I can use all APIs except charging. Since i'm using a developer account and test cards, why do I need to activate card processing? and I didn't find a way to enable it either. Does square take a fee for that?
(that activate page direct me to a registration form which has US related fields (like social security number) but i'm an asian)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to go through Square’s identity verification flow in the Square Dashboard to enable credit card processing before the can process transactions through the Square API in production. If you reside in a country other than the United States, Canada, Australia, the United Kingdom, or Japan you wont be able to process payments through Square.

You can, however, test payments with [test cards](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/testing/test-values#test-credit-card) using your sandbox credentials. You can find your sandbox credentials in your [Developer Dashboard](https://squareup.com/login?return_to=https://connect.squareup.com/apps). The way to view sandbox transactions is to call the [ListTransactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions) endpoint with your sandbox credentials to get a sandbox transaction report.